# add or remove a string from a list based on an if statement

Tags: android, list, checkbox

I have the below code:

```
  if(cb.isChecked())
  {
 selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName()); 
  }

if (!cb.isChecked())
  {
 selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName()); 
  }
testing();
}

private void testing() {
            serverString.setText(null);
               Iterator<String>i = selectedPlanets.iterator();
                while(i.hasNext()){
                String aNum1 = i.next();
                serverString.append(aNum1+",");
                }
```

I then need to iterate through selectedPlanets but the removed ones show up too. By setting the TextView null again, it works if three or more are selected. However, if two are selected, the checked planet also gets removed from the list.

**EDIT:** for anyone who runs into this problem, I solved it by using the else (programmer's block made me lose sense!) and then implementing some other methods that I needed to make it work.

Comment: why should you check like that when its the exact oposite add else instead

Comment: i don't get why all the downvotes...what may seem simple to one person isn't to me

Comment: i dont know why these much down votes is there but you can use if else or elseif to compete with the issue and i hope it will work through the iterator too by puting it in a loop and for eg if it in an evnt driven like in on an on click your second if will be ignored by the s/m

Comment: if you stil has the prob please paste the whole code and explain your issue in detail and where

Comment: @droidhot please see the above code

Comment: just remove the second if clause fully no need of an else either as the string wont be added if not checked please tell me the result one more thing in this case you are checking only 1 check box?????

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16544/discussion-between-fasheikh-and-droidhot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<selectedPlanet.size(); i++) {
    if(planet.isChecked()) {
        selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName()); 
    } else {
       selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to iterate through the set and see if each item is checked or not?

Comment: Ok. so if the checkbox is checked, add all the planets. And if not, remove all of them. Right?

Comment: if the checkbox is checked, add the checked planet. 
if the checkbox is then unchecked, remove that planet

Comment: Then I'm assuming you have multiple `checkbox`s. How do you name them? what is `cb` then?

Comment: i do have multiple checkboxes, they are inflated in the layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16545/discussion-between-fasheikh-and-iturki)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do it like this?

```
if (cb.isChecked()) {
   selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName());
} else {
   selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName());
}
```

Comment: okay, you are right, that he should write like this, but dont you think, how this is going to be a solution of problem, its just a way to minimize/optimize the code, so shouldnt it be just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is 
if `isChecked` **true then add something**

```
if(cb.isChecked())
  {
 selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName()); 
  }
```

if `isChecked` **is not true then remove something**

```
if (!cb.isChecked())
  {
 selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName()); 
  }
```

**Instead of using not true condition you must use else case like**

```
if(cb.isChecked()) {
    selectedPlanets.add(planet.getDisplayName()); 
} else {
   selectedPlanets.remove(planet.getDisplayName()); 
}
```